# Angular FormGroup becomes dirty on disable

Tags: angular

I need to disable an entire `FormGroup` on a certain event.
However I noticed the `FormGroup` becomes `dirty`.

Being that I rely on this `dirty` flag, is there a way to avoid it?
I mean, disabling should **not** cause the `FormGroup` to become `dirty`.

I'm using `FormGroup#disable`

My code is pretty simple, that's why I haven't posted it. Anyway, I simply wrapped the `FormGroup` in an object.

```
public set isDisabled(disabled: boolean) {
    if (disabled) {
        this.formGroup.disable()
    } else {
        this.formGroup.enable()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post  your code here ?

Comment: @JoelJoseph sure!

Comment: You can use `this.profileForm.markAsUntouched(); this.profileForm.markAsPristine();` so form will be looks like as was in initially.

Comment: @JitendraG2 see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of trial-and-error, the solution seems to be using:

```
formGroup.disable({ emitEvent: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the control back to prestine: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markaspristine

Or use markAsUntouched() as Jitendra G2 suggested.